# Smarty foreach loop building array

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

With a smarty foreach-loop I go through an array like this

```
{foreach name=aussen item=order_values from=$module_data}
  HEIAS_PARAMS.push(['order_article', '{$module_data.PRODUCTS_ID}']);
{/foreach}
```

The ouput is like this

```
HEIAS_PARAMS.push(['order_article', '1']);
HEIAS_PARAMS.push(['order_article', '2']);
HEIAS_PARAMS.push(['order_article', '3']);
```

How does the foreach-loop look to get an output like this

```
HEIAS_PARAMS.push(['order_article', '1,2,3']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HEIAS_PARAMS.push(['order_article','{foreach name=aussen item=order_values from=$module_data}{$order_values.PRODUCTS_ID}{if ! $smarty.foreach.aussen.last},{/if}{/foreach}']);
```

I'd write along these lines.

Comment: Something with {if ! smarty.foreach.aussen.last},{/if} is wrong. Unknown token foreach.aussen.last